# Thread Pool Class developement

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I run a multithread application and  I want to limit the number of threads on my machine 
The code concept goes currently like this  (it is just a drft to show the major ideas behind)

```
     //  a List with all the threads I have  
     class MyTHreadList = List<TMyCalcThread>;
     //  a pool class, check how many threads are active 
     //  try to start additions threads once the nr. of running THreads
     //  is below the max_thread_value_running
     class MyTheardPool = Class 
               ThreadList :  MyTHreadList;
                StillRunningTHreads : Integer;
                StartFromThreadID : Integer;
               end; 

     var aTHreadList : MyTHreadList;


      procedure  MainForm.CallCreateThreadFunction( < THREAD PARAMS > );
      begin
            //   just create but do not start here 
            MyTHread := TMyCalcThread.create ( < THREAD PARAMS > ); 
            MyTHread.Onterminate := What_To_do;  
            //   add all threads to a list 
            aTHreadList.add(MyTHread);
      end;  
      /// (A)
      procedure  MainForm.What_To_do () 
      var start : Integer;
      begin
             max_thread_value_running := max_thread_value_running -1;

            if max_thread_value_running < max_thread_count then 
                  begin
                   start := max_thread_count - max_thread_value_running;
                     startThereads(start,StartFromThreadID)
                  end;
      end;

      procedure MainForm.startThereads (HowMany , FromIndex : Integer);
      var   i  : INteger; 
      begin
           for I := FromIndex to HowMany + FromIndexdo 
                begin
                   //  thread[i].start
                end;
      end;



      MainForm.Button ();

      ///  main VCL form , create threats
      for i := 0 to allTHreads do
             begin
               CallCreateTHreadFunction( < THREAD PARAMS > );
             end; 

     ......

     ///  (B)
     while  StillRunningTHreads > 0 do
             begin
                Application.processmessages;
             end;
```

The complete idea is a small list with the Threads, on every individual Thread terminate step I update the number of running threads and start  the now possible max. number of new threads.(A)  Instead of a Function WaitforSingleObject ()  ....   I do a loop at the end to wait for all threads to finish execution. (B)

From the code design I did not find any full example on the net,  I may approach a vaild design or will I run into some trouble which I did not consider right now.
Any comment on the diesign or a better class design is welcome.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have you looked at the OmniThread library?  It may save you some wheel-reinvention and debugging ...

Comment: Most threadpools do not micromanage the threads at all - they rely on blocing producer-consumer queues from which the pool threads draw tasks as they become available.  The pool threads never finish execution, (unless the thread count is reduced), - they just loop around to get more tasks from the queue.

Comment: In case you're interested, an attempt at a thread pool I once did is here: http://sourceforge.net/p/xxm/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Delphi/common/xxmThreadPool.pas

Answer (score 7):

Don't try to micro-manage threads like this.  Just don't.  Either use the Win API threadpool calls, or make your own threadpool from a producer-consumer queue and TThread instances.

When a task is completed, I suggest that the work thread call an 'OnCompletion' TNotifyEvent of the task class with the task as the parameter.  Ths can be set by the issuer of the task to anything they might wish, eg. postMessaging the task instance to the GUI thread for display.

Micro-managing threads, continually creating/waiting/terminating/destroying, Application.processmessages loops etc. is just horrible and almost sure to go wrong at some point.

Waiting for ANYTHING in a GUI event-handler is just bad.  The GUI system is a state-machine and you should not wait inside it.  If you want to issue a task from the GUI thread, do so but don't wait for it - fire it off and forget it until it is completed and gets posted back to a message-handler procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Basically thread-pools are a nice feature (There is an implementation in the Win32 API, however I don't have any experience with it).

There is one basic stumble stone however: You need to remember that a task may be delayed until an empty thread is available. If you need synchronization between different tasks (e.g. tasks are waiting on other tasks) then you have a serious deadlock problem:

1. Just assume that all running tasks wait for a single task which is waiting for a free thread...
2. A similar problem can also happen if your threads wait for the main thread to react while the main thread waits for a new task to start.

If your tasks don't need any further synchronization (e.g. once a task is finished it will just mark itself as finished and the main thread will then later on read the result) you don't need to worry about this.

As a small side note:

- I would use two separate lists: One for free (suspended) threads and one for running threads.
- I'd consider to use an existing Thread-Pool implementation (like Winapi CreateThreadpool) before I created my own...

Answer (score 1):

The loop (B) takes away a lot of CPU power from the threads. Don't wait actively in a loop for threads, use one of the WaitFor.... functions.

Reuse your threads and have a list of "todos" that the threads will execute. Thread creation and destruction can be expensive.

Apart from that I'd recommend that you use an existing library instead of reinventing the wheel. Or use at least the Windows API thread pool functions.